# Link function parameters in directive in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to do addapt the contenteditable directive I foud on angularjs website (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#directives).

My problem is that if I change the value inside the contenteditable div inside my controller, the scope value is updated but the value in the div isn't.
I would like to be able to do something like this in my main controller :

```
$scope.content = $scope.content.concat("added text");
```

This updated the $scope.content but it does not update the contenteditable div. And so, if I click in the div to edit it, my modification is gone.

In order to make it work, I would have to call ctrl.$render from my controller but I can't find any documentation on what is this 4th parameter of the link function.

Does anyone have an idea what this 'ctrl' parameter represents and if by change some know how to solve my problem :)

Comment: The 4th parameter is the controller specified in the `require` parameter.  In this case `ctrl` is an instance of the ngModelController.

Comment: The [forms page](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) and the [NgModelController page](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController) have contenteditable examples, but not the directives page.  Which page are you looking at?

Comment: I am using the one I the forms page except I have removed the line "ctrl.$setViewValue(elm.html());" which I have replaced by ctrl.$render().

Comment: But I have just tried the directive from the NgModelController page and it works like expected :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As of this writing (3/20/2013), there are two problems with the Plunker from the [forms page](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms):

1. missing `form-example`.  
   HTML should be:  `<html ng-app="form-example2">`
2. `contentEditable` should be `contenteditable`.  
   HTML should be: `<div contenteditable ng-model="content">Some content</div>`

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4LAEvoVHqiSjFuuoQDdV?p=preview) with link to append to `$scope.content` in the controller.